# How to position network edge label correctly in networkx?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Im trying to create a graph where each edge of the graph has weight=1, and i want to show it on each edge but the label is not positioned properly how can i fix it?

```
lab = dict([((i, j), f'1') for i, j in gr.edges])
pos = nx.spring_layout(gr)

nx.draw_networkx(gr, with_labels=True, node_color='#7d99f5')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(gr, pos, edge_labels = lab, label_pos=0.5)
```

[image]

this is the output im getting

Comment: You should specify `pos=pos` in `nx.draw_networkx()` as well

Answer (score 2):

You just need to pass the `pos` argument to the `draw_networkx()` function as well as the `draw_networkx_edge_labels()` function. This ensures that the same node/edge layout is used when drawing both the labels as well as the graph itself to the figure.

```
lab = dict([((i, j), '1') for i, j in gr.edges])
pos = nx.spring_layout(gr)

nx.draw_networkx(gr, pos, with_labels=True, node_color='#7d99f5')
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(gr, pos, edge_labels = lab, label_pos=0.5)
```

Gives the desired output:

[image]